# Extend Data View background color to fill card

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dataview-demo-1kpf4h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Ensure you are on the grid view.

All I want is the popular background to extend the entire width of the card (only at the bottom). So it is a different color to the rest of the card above it.The position is correct just need to fill out the bottom of the card only.

How can I do this in the data view card?

I've tried width: 100% but not figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: -2rem` to `.popular-background`. It will offset the padding of its parent `.card`, and fill the entire bottom area of the card.

```css
.popular-background {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: -2rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[image]